# Converting a list of strings to flat strings in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, lisp, elisp

This question may be a bit silly but I just cannot figure it out. Suppose I have a list of strings by

```
(setq foo '("hello" "world"))
```

and now I need to flat them to get separate strings like

```
"hello" "world"
```

how can I make it?
Here the number of the list is unknown in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To pass a list of arguments to a function you can use [`apply`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Calling-Functions.html#Calling-Functions), for example

```
(apply 'insert '("hello " "world"))
```

Comment: But I hope to get two SEPARATE strings.

Comment: Oh, sorry!  What do you exactly want to do?  It may depends on what's your need.

Comment: Actually I am using `call-process` and hope to pass some ARGS(specified in the defintion); now I put all the related arguments in one variable, such as `foo` and I hope it to represent as separate ARGS.

Comment: Then you should use the [`apply`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Calling-Functions.html#Calling-Functions) function